# Is it possible to control two different websites from a single Typo3 installation?

Tags: web-development, cms, multiple-domains, typo3

Is it possible to control two entirely different websites (different domains) from a single Typo3 installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can create as many page trees as you like. Any homepage of these trees can be the starting point of a website and can be linked to any domain accessible on that server. For any pagetree you can use totally different templates.